# Is there a mental poker algorithm that does not rely on commutative encryption?

Tags: encryption, commutative-encryption, mental-poker

The algorithm for mental poker that I saw on Wikipedia and everywhere else relies on an encryption algorithm such that $E_k(E_j(P)) = E_j(E_k(P))$, but I can't find a modern and secure algorithm for which this is true. The only algorithm I found with this property is SRA (I believe that's what it's called) but it relies on modular exponentiation, which is slow and resource intensive compared to a more common algorithm such as AES, not to mention less secure.

Is there a mental poker algorithm that doesn't rely on this property?

Comment: Reference: http://www.bristol.ac.uk/news/2013/9724.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are some other algorithms that do not rely on commutative encryption.

The Wikipedia page for [Mental poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_poker) lists some other examples. It describes a [non-shuffling poker protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_poker#A_non-shuffling_poker_protocol) that uses homomorphic encryption. It has this caveat, though:

> However, the method needs all cards that have already been dealt to be known to all, which in most poker-style games would beat its very purpose.

So it's not practical.

There is also a very interesting paper titled [How to Use Bitcoin to Play Decentralized Poker](http://people.csail.mit.edu/ranjit/papers/poker.pdf). The authors demonstrate how you could use secure multiparty computation with identifiable abort (ID-MPC) to play a decentralized game of poker.

<sub>(Use [this Internet Archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170805230741/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_poker) if the Mental poker page has been updated.)</sub>